# Unable to publish any customization

Tags: acumatica

For some reason I'm now unable to publish any package on my local Acumatica v.6.10 (I dont know how nor why it happened, it's a shared developpment environnement)

Here's the error I get :

The database schema for the current user contains objects that are not included in the dbo schema. Customizations can work incorrectly. For customizations to work properly, modify the schema for the current user.

I'm not a mssql expert, but I dont understand the error, I tried googling it and looking what's the use of dbo, but I didnt manage to find a solution yet.

Do you have any hints about how to debug this issue ? And locate the differences between the dbo schema and the database schema ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you just need to make sure all tables are using the dbo schema. You can do a simple list of these from this query to find any now dbo... SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName, t.[name] AS TableName FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id WHERE s.name <> 'dbo'

Comment: if you find any not dbo, change the table to use dbo and see if that helps.

Comment: also, table changes require you to recycle the site - just in case you still get the error dont forget

Comment: @Brendan Thanks, but nothing is returned by this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have some duplicates Stored Procedures/Views/etc.. in database using Microsoft SQL Management Studio that don't begin with prefix 'dbo' and delete them.

This is an example of the issue:

[image]

There are duplicates stored proc that are in 'acumaticaUser' and 'dbo' schema:
- acumaticaUser.pp_RegisterAdminUser / dbo.pp_RegisterAdminUser

Deleting the duplicates that have 'acumaticaUser' resolves the issue and error messages will disappear.

Comment: The error happens when you update from an older version to v6.1. It's an uncommon occurence.

Comment: You nailed it ! And yes we did an upgrade but a while ago, so I dont understand why the error occurs only now. I deleted the stored procedures and it works.